# how do I convert "YYYY/MM" type date into "MMM-YYYY" in pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

What I want to do:

```
# I have col names in pandas DF such as :
data   2017/01   2017/02  2017/03 ....
 ABC     12       22        08    ....
 EFG     07       16        12    ....
```

I want to convert col names:

```
data   Jan-2017   Feb-2017   Mar-2017  ....
 ABC     12       22        08         ....
 EFG     07       16        12         ....
```

I have tried the following:

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2017/01']), format="%Y/%m")
```

Which, resulted in:

```
  0   2017-01-01
  dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But I am not sure how to get the result I want.
Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are close, need [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format="%Y/%m").strftime('%b-%Y')
print (df)
      Jan-2017  Feb-2017  Mar-2017
data                              
ABC         12        22         8
EFG          7        16        12
```

EDIT:

Thank you [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537001/how-do-i-convert-yyyy-mm-type-date-into-mmm-yyyy-in-pandas-in-python/44537032?noredirect=1#comment76065139_44537032) for idea:

```
df.columns = pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='M').strftime('%b-%Y')
print (df)
      Jan-2017  Feb-2017  Mar-2017
data                              
ABC         12        22         8
EFG          7        16        12
```

Comment: You could also use `pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='M').strftime('%b-%Y')`

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the arrow library. Arrow is supposed to be datetime for humans.
It's clean, simple and intuitive.

```
import arrow
arrow.get('2017/03').format('MMM-YYYY')
```

returns `Mar-2017`